# How to index user table to improve searches by user's real name?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

In an MVC app, which uses Linq to SQL, I have a number of pages that allows filtering users by their real names, emails (and a few other fields). User's first name, last name and all the extra fields are stored in separate columns. Right now, the user table has no indexes (besides the clustered index on user id).

Linq produces a query that has (more or less) this in the where section:

```
(firstName + " " + lastName) LIKE @searchTerm OR
(lastName + " " + firstName) LIKE @searchTerm
```

What would be a good approach if I were to index that?

I was thinking of:

1. Adding 2 complex indexes `(firstName,lastName)` AND `(lastName,firstName)`
2. Add index on `firstName` and another on `lastName`
3. Something else?

Will SQL Server actually use the indexes from the first example on `(firstName + " " + lastName) LIKE @searchTerm` searches?

When I have more time I'll try conducting some tests on my own, but maybe someone already had to solve a similar problem?

---

Solution proposed by onskee made me remembered another one that I've came across a few times when working with databases made by someone else. It involved adding a computed column of all combinations of user's name (first name first, last name first etc.) and other columns, that are supposed to be searchable, and adding a fulltext index on this computed column. I'm not sure how effective it is, I guess I will have to test it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a computed column containing FirstName and LastName, then adding an index to this?  I have not tested performance, but it's one way to try.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD  FullName  AS FirstName + ' ' + LastName
GO


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_FullName ON dbo.Users
(
FullName
) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: That's an interesting option. I guess I will have to prepare a test table and check out how SQL Server would actually behave in each scenario.